# how to bind to property by its name string?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

I get a string array of select label names from API and I want to iterate through it and make div rows, but the problem is that I need to bind selection that user made to different properties in my model.
Those properties are of the same name like in the array I get from backend.
I want something like this:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let propName of array">
    <div class="col-sm">
        <label> {{ propName }} </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
        <select [(ngModel)]="model.getProperty('propName')">
          // ...options
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

is it possible? I'm using angular 10

Comment: Two-way binding to a function isn't a good idea. Please post the structure of `array`, where it's initialized and which property you'd like to bind to. There are better ways to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can access an objects property by using the property name as the index: `person['name']`. In your case `model[propName]` (no quotes aroung the var) should work.

Comment: You could consider switching to reactive forms and do `[formControlName]=propname`

Comment: one of the way to iterate object in Angular is by using `Object.keys(object)` this returns an array of properties, then use `*ngFor` to it, so this `let propName of Object.keys(object)`, u can have a nested for loop to iterate over the array of object.

Comment: thank u all for answers. @GunnarB. 's solution works perfectly.